# Angular2 Build: Cannot find name 'Promise' only in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, typescript, angular

I am getting started with Angular2 and followed the quickstart here: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

It seems to work fine when I do npm install but I want to run it in Visual Studio and I will be making in Asp.Net/C# and not NodeJS.

When I build the solution in VS I get this:

[image]

I think in nodejS it works because in the package.json we have this:

```
"postinstall": "typings install",
```

entire package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

But problem is I am using Visual studio. How can I just build the solution and make it run without using `npm start`

Comment: It looks like ES6 or typescript code make it to the runtime that cannot interpret this. This can either mean that you need to polyfill something (e.g. import core-js to polyfill a lot of things). Or that you're missing a build step (e.g. compile typescript to es5).

Comment: I don't have any build step. I pasted code as is from Angular. Again I re-emphasize it works in Node using npm start but does not working in Visual  when I build the solution.

Comment: A "Promise" is relatively new to JS, it may be in your NodeJS runtime but not in the runtime utilized by Visual Studio. I'm not familiar with VS so I'm not sure what it runs internally but perhaps this can be configured?

Answer (score 1):

I think you must use es6-shim to get these errors away. Try this:

```
typings install dt~es6-shim --save --global
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I had to install typings first:   
`npm install typings -g`

but this suggestion worked after that

Comment: thats right. You need to habe typings installed through npm before you can add any typing to your project.